# Cannot install ESXi error "Panic: Can't find .text section in VMkernel Elf file"

Tags: vmware-esxi, installation

I am trying to install ESXi 6.0 by CDROM and receive this error:

```
Panic: Can't find .text section in VMkernel Elf file
```

I have 12GB RAM and Intel i5 4 core 3.3Ghz CPU.  I thought possibly this may be related to the BIOS, I upgraded it to the latest version, and this still occurs. Motherboard is Gigabyte GA-H55M-UD2H.

Any ideas on things I should check to resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked the integrity of the ISO file in your CDROM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests it seems the motherboard or something else in the system is incompatible. The Gigabyte motherboard is incompatible. I also tried a second system I had around,  [BIOSTAR A770E3 AM3](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813138179)  this also seems to be incompatible.

Tried these approaches:

- I tried the CD in other systems, was able to get to the ESXi install screen
- Tried several CDs and write verify
- swapped out CD ROM drives
- tried versions ESXi installs: 5.0, 5.5, 6.0